# jquery ui sortable plugin not saving to database

Tags: php, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery

Ok this one should be fairly simple but Im finding it very hard.  I have found a great sortable example on http://www.xmech.net/programming/jquery-ui-sortable-tutorial/ which uses the jquery ui to sort a list and save it to the database.

Mine allows you to drag and drop but is not saving to the database.  here is my jquery function

```
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
 $(document).ready(function(){
$("#menu-pages").sortable({
update: function(event, ui) {
    $.post("sortable.php", {type: "orderPages", pages: $('#menu-  pages').sortable('serialize') });
}
 });
 });
 </script>
```

and my php / html

```
   <ul class="menu" id="menu-pages">
   <?php
   mysql_select_db($database_dbconnet, $dbconnet);
    $resultq = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `section` ORDER BY `sectorder` ASC", $dbconnet) or die(mysql_error());

   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultq)){
    printf('<li id="page_%s">%s</li>', $row['idsect'], $row['sectname']);
}
   ?>

  </ul>
```

and my php file called sortable.php

```
   require('../../../Connections/dbconnet.php');
   parse_str($_POST['pages'], $pageOrder);
    foreach ($pageOrder['pages'] as $key => $value) {
mysql_select_db($database_dbconnet, $dbconnet);
     mysql_query("UPDATE `section` SET `sectorder` = '$key' WHERE `idsect` = '$value'",     $dbconnet) or die(mysql_error());
  }
```

as you can see I have even tried to keep the same names as the example but I cant make it go.

Comment: Are you getting some mysql errors?

Comment: @MikeBrant no errors returned at all.  If I refresh the page or check the database nothing has changed at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In looking at your jQuery, it seems you are posting JSON.  I am guessing that `$_POST` is not being populated, because it only gets populated automatically for posts received in an form-encoded format.  You need to read PHP raw input to get the JSON string and then you need to decode that JSON string into an object.  That would be something like this:

```
$json = file_get_content('php://input');
$object = json_decode($json);
$type = $object->type;
$pages = $object->pages;
```

You should always at least do some basic debugging attempts before posting a question, as I imagine the fact the $_POST is empty would at least have enabled you to focus your question on the issue at hand (i.e. this has nothing to do with either sortable or the database).

Comment: Hi @MikeBrant  thanks for your reply.  Im very new to ajax and json I have not used just yet.  I was following that tut as it seemed basic and I needed no real knowledge of ajax or json to understand it. am i right in understanding this is how it should be

Comment: $json = file_get_content('php://input');
$object = json_decode($json);
$type = $object->type;
$pages = $object->pages;

parse_str($_POST['pages'], $pageOrder);
foreach ($pageOrder['pages'] as $key => $value) {
 mysql_select_db($database_dbconnet, $dbconnet);
    mysql_query("UPDATE `section` SET `sectorder` = '$key' WHERE `idsect` = '$value'", $dbconnet) or die(mysql_error());
}

Comment: @DanielRobinson No, there will be no values in `$_POST` at all. Var_dump your `$pages` value to see what you have.  In all likelihood it is a serialized format of the sortable data that you will need to further de-serialize in order to work with it (sorry not that familiar with sortable).

Comment: What do you get as var_dump for `$json`? I am thinking that perhaps your serialized data is not forming valid JSON, causing `json_decode()` to fail.

Comment: Odd, seems raw input is not being passed. And what happens if you `var_dump($_POST)`?